# redis serializar session en c# net asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

Estoy usando redis y estoy intentando almacenar la sesion de usuario en un azure redis, he probado almacenar strings dentro y funciona con `session.add("nombre", objeto)` y me funciona para string comunes y corrientes pero cuando trato de guardar la session dentro (dado que nose porque no lo hace automaticamente luego de configurar web.conf, al intentar `session.add("unasession",session);`
me da el error :

> El tipo 'System.Web.HttpSessionStateWrapper' del ensamblado
>   'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' no está marcado como serializable.

Answer (score 0):

No funciona porque los datos que introduces la Session no están serializados. 
Serializa los datos y ya está.
Los datos puedes serializarlos y desserializarlos, cuando sea necesario.
Echa un vistazo a:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/serialization-and-deserialization

Por ejemplo:

```
//Creamos objeto Coche
CocheCoche objCoche =new Coche
{ 
IdCoche = 1, 
Marca = "Mercedes", 
Modelo = "C220K" 
};

//Serializar objCoche a XMLstring 
xmlCoche = objCoche.SerializarToXml();

//Deserializar XML a objCocheCoche 
cocheDeserializado = xmlCoche.DeserializarTo<Coche>();
```

Suerte:

Comment: Disculpa pero como serializo la session? ya he visto esa documentacion pero no logro entender donde agregar esto, agrego en hoomecontroller.cs una clase llamada public void session y agregarle un adorno [serialize] ?

Comment: Fíjate en el ejemplo que puse al modificar la respuesta